# k'th highest of two sorted arrays

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and I'm running into what I'm sure are beginner errors. I'm getting an error `invalid identifier character U+2013` seemingly everywhere I'm subtracting. Am I some how not using the arithmetic operator properly? I'm also getting the errors `unexpected name, expecting semicolon or newline or }` and `non-declaration statement outside function body` but I'm not too sure what's causing it. It mainly seems like the issue is within my if statements above the for loop. I thought it was because I'm reassigning already declared variables, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Any help would be much appreciated and if anyone has some tips in general for debugging Go that would be great too.

```
package main

import "fmt"


func main() {
    a := []int{
        13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
    }

    b := []int{
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
    }

    k := 8

    result := kthSmallest(a, b, k)
    fmt.Printf("%v", result)

}

func kthSmallest(a []int, b []int, k int) int {
    if k >= len(a) + len(b) {
       fmt.Printf("The range is not large enough")
       return 0
    }

    var lowA, lowB, highA, highB int = 0, 0, k - 1, k - 1

    if len(a) < k - 1 {
        highA = len(a) - 1;
    }

    if len(b) < k - 1 {
        highB = len(b) - 1;
    }

    if highA + highB < k {
        return 0;
    }

    var midA, midB int = 0, 0
    var result int = 0

    for k > 0 {
        midA = lowA + (highA - lowA)/2;
        midB = lowB + (highB - lowB)/2;

        if a[midA] >= b[midB] {

            k = k - (midB - lowB + 1);
            result = b[midB];
            highA = midA - 1;
            lowB = midB + 1;

        } else if a[midA] < b[midB] {

            k = k - (midA - lowA + 1);
            result = a[midA];
            highB = midB - 1;
            lowA = midA + 1;

        }

    }


    return result
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[U+2013](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) (or '–') is a fancy version of '-' (or [U+2d](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm)) for people who are big into typography. If you type a dash on your keyboard, you'll get the right character, if you copied something in from a web site, a word processor, or an email, it might have been 'helpfully' replaced along with way with the wrong dash, which Go doesn't understand. This also happens a lot with the double-quote character.

You should be able to search and replace the fancy dash in your text editor or IDE.

Comment: Well, that'll do it. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated my code, but I'm still having a little trouble. When the value of `k` is set to 2 through 6, it seems to work, but when it's set to 1, the `result` is set to 0, when it should be 1. When it's set to 7 the `result` is 3 and setting it higher than 7, the execution times out. Am I just totally over looking an error in my logic?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks again.